# Find documents with at least one null value in array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

Our data structure looks as follows

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": [
        {
            "qux": true
        },
        {
            "qux": null
        },
        {
            "qux": false
        }
    ]
}
```

In other documents, the number of items in the `baz` array might vary.

We're looking to find documents that have at least one `null` value for `qux` in the `baz` array.

We have tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "baz.qux"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this will not return documents that have e.g. one `true` and one `null` value for `qux` in the `baz` array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether the field having null or not using the missing query.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter": {
                "missing" : { "field" : "baz.qux" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can check the elastic document as well on below link:

Documentation: [Is null Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html#_missing_query)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a [nested mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Mapping:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "baz": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "qux": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "baz",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "baz.qux"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```